# Cannot connect Arduino Mega 2560

Tags: arduino-mega

I was able to work with the same Arduino on the same laptop yesterday. However, the Arduino IDE is unable to connect the Arduino Mega 2560 today. I tried with a different Arduino Mega 2560 but the Arduino IDE doesn't connect it. My laptop is able to recognize COM Port but in the Arduino IDE the "Tools - Ports option" is missing.

[image]

[image]

Comment: what is your question? ..... which version of Arduino IDE are you using?

Comment: I am using Arduino IDE 2.0.3. My question is that how do I connect my Arduino Mega 2560 to the Arduino IDE on my laptop? As the first picture shows, the Device Manager is able to recognize the device. However, in the Arduino IDE, it said "NO PORTS DISCOVERED". I have read most of the articles online and tried their methods but none of them works. I am wondering why my laptop can recognize the device while my Arduino IDE cannot. Furthermore, the Arduino IDE can connect with the device until yesterday. I changed nothing on my laptop.

Comment: 2.0.3 may be broken ... try earlier versions ... or try the nightly build